# How can we access Relation Database System from other regions in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have two **autoscaled** instance in two regions 1. US West and 2. Singapore.

and I have only one RDS instance that is in US West.

I need to access this RDS instance from above two instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RDS Security Group, You need create a rule to allow incoming access on port 3306 (assuming this is MySQL RDS) from the public IP address of both the EC2 instances.

Comment: those two instances are autoscaled , means public IP are changable... I am using ELB's. how can I link these ??

Comment: There is no straight forward way. You need to write a script, which will pull the Public IP addresses of the instances that are managed by the load balancer , and then the script should add these Ip addresses in the Security groups of RDS. Also you need the script to poll both the regions in order to get the IP addresses of both the instnaces.

Comment: You start writing a script and I can help you where you get stuck. You can choose any of these SDKs: http://aws.amazon.com/tools/